# Sets: intersection distributes over intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I'm asking for proof verification on this. It's a pretty intuitive theorem, which it's kind of strange (perhaps difficult?) to reason about, in my opinion.

Theorem:

Let $\Lambda$ be an arbitrary indexing set for a collection of sets $\{B_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in \Lambda}$. Let C be a set. Then $C \cap (\cap_{\alpha \in \Lambda}B_\alpha) = \cap_{\alpha \in \Lambda}(C \cap B_\alpha)$

Proof:

1) Let $x \in C \cap (\cap_{\alpha \in \Lambda}B_\alpha)$. Then $x \in C$ and $x \in B_\alpha$ for all $\alpha \in \Lambda$. So $x \in C \cap B_\alpha$ for all $\alpha \in \Lambda$. This mean that $x \in \cap_{\alpha \in \Lambda}(C \cap B_\alpha)$.

2) Let $x \in \cap_{\alpha \in \Lambda}(C \cap B_\alpha)$. Then $x \in C \cap B_\alpha$ for all $\alpha \in \Lambda$. So $x \in C$ and $x \in B_\alpha$ for all $\alpha \in \Lambda$. Meaning  the same as $x \in C \cap (\cap_{\alpha \in \Lambda}B_\alpha)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof looks fine to me, having used element chasing to show that $$C \cap \left(\bigcap_{\alpha \in \Lambda}B_\alpha\right) \subseteq \bigcap_{\alpha \in \Lambda}(C \cap B_\alpha)$$ and then having shown that $$ \bigcap_{\alpha \in \Lambda}(C \cap B_\alpha)\subseteq C \cap \left(\bigcap_{\alpha \in \Lambda}B_\alpha\right)$$

Formatting tip: `\cap`:= $\cap$, and `\bigcap` : = $\bigcap$

Comment: Great! :-) I can do math! :-) And thanks for the tip.

Comment: You're welcome! Yes you can do math!

Comment: Yes, I should have explained what the 1) and 2) were for.